# Django cannot find the settings.py file

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I forgot the password to my admin page. I found a solution but in order to change it I had to include `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to system path and pointed it to settings.py file in my folder, I did so. Since then I'm getting this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\manda\\PycharmProjects\\firstsite\\firstsite\\settings'
```

I revert back all my changes I made in files and removed 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' from environment variable but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit obvious, but did you try to restart your system? Otherwise I can't be of must use.

But in the future if you remember the username of the admin-account you can change the password in the django-shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
$ >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
$ >>> user = User.objects.get(username='your_username')
$ >>> user.set_password('raw_password')
$ >>> user.save()
```

Comment: I resolved the issue by calling the settings manually. Thanks for code I will use that now